# How can I give each element a different position?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to return 3 elements. First of them should be on the left. Second should be in the middle. Third should be on the right.

How can I give them different starting positions in React?

```
 return (

    <div>
      {[1,2,3].map(function (n) {
        return (
          <div key={n} >


            <h3>{'With key ' + n}</h3>
            <p>{n}</p>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: What does this have to do with React? If you want them to appear next to each other you need to *style* them, e.g. using flex box.

Comment: @UmutArpat I have added a flex based solution for you to check,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks Like you are doing it correct.

.map() will return it in the same order you want. Positioning CSS looks missing

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

JSX should look like

return (

```
<div class="parent">
  {[1,2,3].map(function (n) {
    return (
      <div key={n} >


        <h3>{'With key ' + n}</h3>
        <p>{n}</p>
      </div>
    );
  })}
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

do it with css - if this is the specific cases:

```
const class=['left', 'mid', 'right']

return (

    <div>
      {[1,2,3].map(function (n,i) {
        return (
          <div key={n} className={class[i]} >


            <h3>{'With key ' + n}</h3>
            <p>{n}</p>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
```